# Add Class into uses section in Propel behavior

Tags: propel, behavior, symfony-2.0

That's it. I created behavior and only some of its classes are added into head with `use` due to my behavior.

E.g. behavior creates new table named `acme`. Propel generator adds to my `Foo` class (app/propel/AppPropelModel/AcmeBundle/om/BaseFoo.php) `AcmeBehavior` and `AcmeBehaviorQuery`, but not `AcmeBehaviorPeer`.

I don't want to mess with full class name in behaviour-building class `AcmeBehaviorObjectBuilderModifier.php`
How could I make Propel add `use AppPropelModel\HornsAndHooves\AcmeBundle\AcmeBehaviorPeer` to the destination class file as well?

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do (or what isn't working). Are you saying you have a Behavior you wrote which creates a table, but that the `*Peer` class isn't being generated? Is that the only issue?

Comment: No, class is generated. It is not _written_ into `uses` block.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a class and want to add it to "use" block, you have to declare that class in the builder. Just call declareClass in this function with your full namespace:

```
class MyBehavior extends Behavior {
    ...

    public function objectMethods($builder)
    {
        $builder->declareClass('MyNamespace\\MyBundle\\Subfolder');
    }
}
```

This will result:

```
use MyNamespace\MyBundle\Subfolder;

abstract class MyModelClass extends ...
```